# How to check a key is exist or not in gson parsing android

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

I am parsing a json response using gson. However in my case I am getting different response for success and failure.
    So I am unable to parse the data, because in my utility class I have created some serilized field those are not present for both the scenario.
    e.g. when registration is success I am using `user` key to get the user details while when registration is failed I am using `error` field to get error message.

I have  knowledge about json parsing and in that we we do parsing step by step like if success is true then parse for user details otherwise parse for error. Again in json parsing we have method `has` which check a key is exist or not. And I am looking for something similar in gson also.

Below is my code snippet please check it

**Get Register Data from Server**

```
 private void getRegisterData(String email, String password, String full_name,String phone) {
    WdApplication= (WAdvantageApplication) this.getApplication();
    RequestQueue queue = application.getRequestQueue();
    HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headerMap.put(RequestHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, RequestHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON);

    HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    dataMap.put("email", email);
    dataMap.put("password", password);
    dataMap.put("phone", phone);
    dataMap.put("fullname", full_name);

    GsonRequest<RegisterDetails> request = new GsonRequest<RegisterDetails>(GsonRequest.Method.POST, URLConstant.REGISTER_URL, RegisterDetails.class, headerMap, dataMap, successListener, failureListener);
    queue.add(request);


}

    private Response.Listener successListener = new Response.Listener<RegisterDetails>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(RegisterDetails registerDetails) {

       Log.e("success", "Success");

        finish();
    }
};

private Response.ErrorListener failureListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        Log.e("fail", "Registration failed");



    }
};
```

my `RegisterDetails` class

```
    @SerializedName("user")
    private UserDetails userDetails;

   @SerializedName("success")
   private String success;


   @SerializedName("error")
   Information info;
```

So for success is true I want only `user` part and for success is false I want `error` part.

If I am doing anything wrong please rectify me , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking about, but in gson if you are getting success key and user key (if it's success) and error (if something goes wrong)in single response, you can code something like this.

```
if(registerDetails.getSuccess().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
{
   // use registerDetails.getUserDetails();
}
else
{
   // use registerDetails.getInfo();
}
```

Comment: But when success is true it is giving me error and when I commented the code for `error` it is working fine.

Comment: Can we have json structure for both success and failure scenario

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about GSON but if you use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), you can provide an annotation like this

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

and then you can use the same model class for success or failure, if it is a success, the userDetails will be set, if it is a failure, the error part will be set.

Comment: Yeah, That's what I am looking for but unfortunately I am using gson

Comment: Any reason why you can't switch to Jackson